# Find elements on page without searching entire document

Tags: html, powershell, dom, getelementsbytagname, dom-traversal

To improve performance, I would like to perform getElementsByTagName("td") without having it search the entire document. Is there a way to narrow the scope searching for these elements? Here is my code:

```
 $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td") | ? {($_.className -match 'NodeDocument')
```

The problem with this is that it takes over 10 minutes to return the results and I would like to narrow the scope of what is searched so it goes faster and doesn't return unwanted elements.

As an example, I only want to search for the highlighted elements in the image below, and not within the folders above an beneath. Is there a way to specify to only look within the 'Conventional' folder?

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Thanks for the replies, I will try to implement XPath. For what its worth, here is a screenshot of the HTML. #1 is the element of the 'Conventional' Folder. #2 is the first document element within the folder.
[image]

Update: Tried Frodo's method of calling .getElementsByTagName() on the $conventional folder in Chrome inspector. Here is a screenshot of result:

[image]

Comment: Xpath is an alternative that might work better but it's impossible to write a sample without seeing the code(html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to implement XPath but figure I will face some trouble. I added a screenshot of my html to the original post.

Comment: If you want to play with `SelectNodes()` and xpath you would need to replace IE com-object with ex. HTML Agility Pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Instead of referencing the `$conventional` folder (which I found out does not have the "td" NodeDocuments as children), I created a new `$DocContainer` which points to a div element which DOES have the NodeDocuments as children:

```
$DocContainer = $conventional.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling
```

Using this `$DocContainer` I can now say:

```
$documents = $DocContainer.getElementsByTagName("td") | ? {($_.className -match 'NodeDocument')
```

Special thank you to Frode F. for giving me the thought to reference a new element which is actually the parent container.

For others with similar issues:

Take advantage of the chrome inspector / console to test where your elements are within the DOM tree. Chrome's built-in inspector / console is very powerful and can save a lot of time and hassle. Methods like `.parentNode`, `.nextSibling`, `childNodes` are key for DOM traversal. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great to hear that you found a solution! :-) Quick comment: This is really just a duplicate answer. The only difference is the way you access the container-node which is unique to your system and can't be reused by others. That's why I said you might need to try different container-nods to get it to work. Answers on SO should also benefit future readers, so it's the "game plan" that is the solution here.

Answer (score 3):

How about locating the container-node first and search inside of that? That would limit you down to ex. 5 `td`-nodes that needs to be filtered through `where-object` and not 1000+ like you may have now.

```
$conventional = $ie.Document.getElementById('OurLibrary_LibTocUC$LandingPanel$toc1$ExpertTree1_nl_23')
$documents = $conventional.getElementsByTagName("td") | ? { $_.className -match 'NodeDocument' }
```

Comment: Thanks Frode. I will try this out now

Comment: Hmm, not working. `$documents` comes back as empty when I try this method. Are you sure that you can call `.getElementsByTagName()` on a div element? I would think it would work, but its not

Comment: Are you sure `$conventional` found the node? I had a typo in the id for the container, so copy it from the source to be safe. Or you could try setting `$conventional` to one the table-elements or another type of node that wraps the td-elements you are interested in. I tested it on a random website with a container-div in `$conventional` and using `$conventional.getElementsbyTagName("a")` to get all links.

Comment: Yes it is finding the correct node, and yet nothing is returning when I call getElementsByTagName() on it. Odd that it worked for you

Comment: Tried it out in chrome console (see original post for new screenshot) and it returned '[]' which I assume is a nodelist? But I am unable to access its content using an index. Any ideas?

Comment: So it appears that the "td" elements of class 'NodeDocument' are not children of the Conventional folder

Comment: I've already suggested setting conventional to one of the tables or any other parent container of the links. Have you tried that?

Comment: No I will go ahead and try that now. My only concern is that the parent elements of NodeDocument have nothing unique for me to reference them by (Can't reference ID for anything on this site as the ID values are constantly changing). I will dig into this. Thanks